# req.user undefined using Express & Node & Passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am currently creating a small user authentication app using Node + Express + Passport. When the user logs in, they are rerouted automatically to the index page "/" and a session **should** be established with passports authentication. For some reason when trying to `console.log(req.user)`, it is returning "undefined".

The authentication with passport seems to be working properly with the post route

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/home",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), (req, res) => {
})
```

But the session is not being established with the user model. I'd like to eventually store the userId in the session. Here is a look at my current set up with user model and passport implementation on the server file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const user = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = user;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const express = require("express"),
        mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
        session = require("express-session"),
        User = require("./models/user"),
        passport = require('passport'),
        LocalStragety = require('passport-local'),
        app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/shopping_cart_app", { useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then(console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(session({
        secret: "secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStragety(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/home",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
}), (req, res) => {
})
```

I've tried looking into Passports config a bit more but on the documentation provided, it states that once `passport.authenticate` runs, a session with the user is established. Any tips would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this may seem simple, but have you tried `req.body.user`?

The `req.body` contains the data submitted by the user. The documentation suggest that you use a body parser to populate the information because it's undefined by default. However, instead of using the app object I use express router without parsing.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/home",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.user);

})
```

for more information: [req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, In my project, it is working.

> LocalStrategy

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var admins = mongoose.model('admins');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var moment = require('moment');

// User
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  console.log("deserializing " + obj);
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use('adminlogin',new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) { 
        admins.findOne({ 'email' :  username },
            function(err, user) {
                //console.log(username);
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!user){
                    //console.log('Username '+username+' does not Exist. Pleasr try again.');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Username/Password. Please try again.' });               
                }
                if (!isValidPasswordAdmin(user, password)){
                    //console.log('Invalid Password');
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Password. Please try again.' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            }
        );

    })
);
var isValidPassword = function(user, app_pin){
    return bCrypt.compareSync(app_pin, user.app_pin);
}

var isValidPasswordAdmin = function(user, password){
    return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}

module.exports = passport;
```

> Login Route

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    admins.find({}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('internal database error');
            req.flash('error', 'Database Error');
            res.redirect('/admins');
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('adminlogin', function (err, user, info) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    req.flash('error', 'Database Error');
                    res.redirect('/admins');
                } else if (!user) {
                    req.flash('error', info.message);
                    res.redirect('/admins');
                } else {
                    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            req.flash('error', 'Database Error');
                            res.redirect('/admins');
                        } else {
                            res.redirect('/admins/home');
                        }
                    });
                }
            })(req, res, next);
        }
    });
});
```